# XSLT problem: regular expressions for attribute values

Tags: regex, xml, xslt

Consider the following XML:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="eclas.xsl"?>

  <collection>
    <record>
      <datafield tag="150">
        <subfield code="a">Abandon des études</subfield><!--accepted FR-->
        <subfield code="9">fre</subfield>
      </datafield>
      <datafield tag="150">
        <subfield code="a">Student drop-out</subfield><!--accepted EN-->
        <subfield code="9">eng</subfield>
      </datafield>
      <datafield tag="450">
        <subfield code="a">Décrochage scolaire</subfield><!-- NOT accepted term FR-->
        <subfield code="9">fre</subfield>
      </datafield>
      <datafield tag="450">
        <subfield code="a">Abandon scolaire</subfield><!-- NOT accepted term FR-->
        <subfield code="9">fre</subfield>
      </datafield>
      <datafield tag="450">
        <subfield code="a">Abandon de la scolarité</subfield><!-- NOT preferred term FR-->
        <subfield code="9">fre</subfield>
      </datafield>
    </record>
    <record>
      <datafield tag="151">
        <subfield code="a">Egypte</subfield>
        <subfield code="9">fre</subfield>
      </datafield>
      <datafield tag="151">
        <subfield code="a">Egypt</subfield>
        <subfield code="9">eng</subfield>
      </datafield>
      <datafield tag="451">
        <subfield code="a">République arabe d&apos;Egypte</subfield>
        <subfield code="9">fre</subfield>
      </datafield>
      <datafield tag="451">
        <subfield code="a">République arabe unie</subfield>
        <subfield code="9">fre</subfield>
      </datafield>
      <datafield tag="451">
        <subfield code="a">United Arab Republic</subfield>
        <subfield code="9">eng</subfield>
      </datafield>
    </record>
</collection>
```

It's a sample from a large thesaurus.
I need help with my regular expression that can either select between 150 or 151 and 450 or 451.

Here's the xslt code I have trouble with:

```
<xsl:for-each select="datafield[contains(@tag, '150|151' )]">
...
</xsl:for-each>
```

I'm trying to loop over the datafield elements that have either 150 or 151 as value. 
My regular expression does not seem to work. I have tried several things to no avail.

Comment: With XSLT questions, it's really important to say which version of the language you are using.

Answer (score 1):

`contains()` takes a string not a regex as the second parameter so your code is looking for the string `150|151`. You can't do regex in XSLT 1.0. However using the `choose()` function you can do multiple `contains()`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310300/xslt-contains-for-multiple-strings#2310326) question for more info.

Comment: Edited XSLT -> XSLT 1.0. You can of course do regular expression processing with more up-to-date versions of the language.

Answer (score 0):

The `contains` function does not take a regular expression as the second argument, just a simple string which it checks is in the first string or not. You should be using `matches`...

```
 <xsl:for-each select="datafield[matches(@tag, '^150$|^151$')]">
```

Or slightly better...

```
<xsl:for-each select="datafield[matches(@tag, '^(150|151)$')]">
```

Note the extra symbols to prevent "1500" being matched, for example.

However, `matches` is XSLT 2.0 only, and your use of `<?xml-stylesheet` suggests you are doing the transformation in the browser, which would really be XSLT 1.0 only. If this is the case, then you can use `contains` with a little extra effort

```
<xsl:for-each select="datafield[contains('|150|151|', concat('|', @tag, '|') )]">
```

Again, the extra use of `|` is to prevent `1500` being picked up, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You want to match either of the following 4 strings:
*150*, *151*, *450* and *451*. Note that:

- the first char is either `1` or `4`,
- the second char is always `5`,
- and the last char is either `0` or `1`.

So the regex matching all of them is `^[14]5[01]$`.

I put `^` and `$` anchors to prevent from matching such a string
as a part of longer text (e.g. *31508*).

So in *XSLT 2.0* you can write:

```
<xsl:for-each select="datafield[matches(@tag, '^[14]5[01]$')]">
```